# Why are "providers" in components or modules not tree-shakable?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I know if want the service to be tree-shakable, it needs to use `providerIn`.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestProviderInService {
  ....
}
```

But why are service registrations in the "providers" of modules/components not tree-shakable?

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [TestModuleService],
})
```

---

```
@Component({
  providers: [TestComponentService],
})
export class HelloComponent {
  ....
}
```

Only `TestModuleService` and `TestComponentService` are bundled into the [dist files](https://github.com/lichunbin814/tree-shaking-test/blob/main/dist/demo/main.js).

[image]

---

**My research**

I'm guessing the key is the [hard reference](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22414#issuecomment-1004187711), but I'm not sure how this happens.

---

**My Question**

Is there anyone/article that can explain Angular's tree-shaking difference theory between `providerIn` and `providers`?

Comment: you are explicitly importing a service in a file and you are explicitly using it in providers array. from JS point of view the service is used in the actual code and therefore cannot be excluded from bundle. that is it

Answer (score 3):

ProvidedIn is an alternative to use providers. As Angular explained, providedIn root leads to providing a service on application level, but still angular application can tree shake the service if it was not used. If you use the providers way, then the application considers the service as a dependency and will not tree shake it.

If you use providedIn you won't need to provide the component under providers array.

Check this Angular doc for more information about the dependency injection https://angular.io/guide/providers

I also found this good article that explains in examples, how the tree shaking works.

https://coryrylan.com/blog/tree-shakeable-providers-and-services-in-angular

Comment: Thanks, so if I develop an angular library, where a component within the library has a dependency injected with the @Optional decorator, and the consumer application must provide the dependency (say the in providers array) - if it is not provided, will this optional dependency from the library bee tree shaken?

Comment: If it is just injected but not used the yes it will bee tree shaken