# Tree shaking vs Lazy Loading

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lazy-loading, tree-shaking

In Angular, we can use `providedIn: 'root'` to make a service tree shakeable. And we can use `loadChildren()` in our router to specify a lazily loaded module. What's the difference between these two terms 'tree shakeable' and 'lazy loaded'? Do they both only happen when you initially build the project? Why not just call providedIn root services 'lazy loaded services'?

Comment: If you click the tags you added ([lazy-loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lazy-loading) and [tree-shaking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tree-shaking)) it will show you a short description of what they mean.

Answer (score 1):

1. What's the difference between these two terms 'tree shakeable' and 'lazy loaded'?

*Tree shaking* is a step in a build process that removes unused code from a code base. E.g. components/modules you created, but never used. They get completely eliminated. Same with services, but there are [nuances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73843252/why-are-providers-in-components-or-modules-not-tree-shakable).

Then the code important for the app gets split into bundles by a module bundler. The more lazy loaded elements the app has - the more bundles it will be split into.

*Lazy loading* means the object will be loaded only when it is needed. E.g. separate lazy-loaded admin module: it has important for the app code, but the code (bundle) won't be sent to ordinary users as they don't have admin permissions, hence they don't need admin-features-related code.

2. Do they both only happen when you initially build the project?

Yes. During build process unused code gets identified and removed (tree shaking), while the important code gets split into bundles for the purpose of not sending all the app code in one big chunk (including the features the user might not even need). Some of the bundles will be loaded lazily on certain user actions.

3. Why not just call providedIn root services 'lazy loaded services'?

I presume that `providedIn: root` services may not be lazy loaded, e.g. the service code will be sent to the user immediately on page init (however the service itself will be initialized on the service usage).